# Android signed int to unsigned int conversion

Tags: android, colors, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to convert a signed decimal to an unsigned decimal, but I don't know how to do that.

The Android device is communicating with another iOS device, and we need to send color codes from one platform to another. Because these platforms has different data types (Java signed data types and iOS unsigned data types) we need to make conversions in order to have the same colors on both sides.

This is what I have made so far:

```
// Parse and retrieve color code from the backend server
int unsignedColor = getColorFromBackend();

// Now add an alpha channel 'FF' and make it unsigned color
int signedColor = toSignedColor(unsignedColor);
// The signed value is -14701818

// Now try to make the conversion back, from signed to unsigned
int conversion = toUnsignedColor(signedColor);
// The value is: 129712 which is not the value I want (2075398)

private int toUnsignedColor(int signedColor) {
   String hex = Integer.toHexString(signedColor);
   hex = hex.substring(2, hex.length() - 1);
   // hex = "1FAB06";

   int unsignedInt = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
   return unsignedInt;
}

private int toSignedColor(int unsignedColor) {
   String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFFFF & unsignedColor));
   // hexColor = "#FF1FAB06";
   int signedColor = Color.parseColor(hexColor);
   return signedColor;
}

// This is an example
private int getColorFromBackend() {
   return 2075398;
}
```

Comment: `trying to convert a signed decimal to an unsigned decimal`. You mean: signed integer to unsigned integer? Please give an example. And indicate why that would be problematic.

Comment: I wonder how you send the data between Android an IOS. Because you would send four bytes in either direction i would think for an integer. Be it signed or unsigned.

Comment: Please give an example of receiving data from IOS that is problematic.

Comment: int color = json.getInt("color");

Comment: That does not clear up anything. You are not serious.

Comment: @greenapps It actually is an issue, though I am not sure it is his issue. When saving to json, an unsaved int, of 2147483648 or higher, it will not be able to be parsed as a signed int.

Comment: He he.. Finally an example.

Comment: Parse it as a big int or long int or 64 bit int.

Answer (score 1):

The best and clearest way to pass colors in json, without signed/unsigned issues, is to pass them as a Hex string.
This will also make the json color value more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to convert the signed integer value back to unsigned by shifting the bits:

```
// 2075398;
int unsigned = parseColor("color_code");

// -14701818
int signedColor = unsigned | (0xFF << 24);

// Now convert back to signed integer, wihch is: 2075398 (no alpha)
int converted = signedColor & ((1 << 24) - 1);


// With alpha
view.setColor(signedColor);
```

Comment: This code is ludicrous, as you are just removing the alpha completely, or setting it to 255, and has nothing to do with the original alpha value. The only correct way to do it,a and it is simple,  is to read it from the json as a long, and then cast it to an int. That way, it will correctly read the unsigned positive value, and then when you cast it, it will turn to a signed (possibly negative) int value.